# How to send a form data from external html file to django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, forms

Im trying to send a form data from an external html file (not inside the project of django) to a django database but i need to pass a CRSK token in that form, if i do it with a form inside project django its very easy, but since is a form outside of django the way to do it its different. in the view i have this:

```
def coords_save(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        form = UbicacionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ubicaciones = Ubicacion.objects.all().order_by('-fecha')
            data = '<ul>'
            for ubicacion in ubicaciones:
                data += '<li>%s %s</li>' % (ubicacion.nombre, ubicacion.user)
            data += '</ul>'
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'ok':True,'msg':data}),mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'ok':False,'msg':'debes llenar los campos'}),mimetype='application/json')
```

and this is the html:

```
<script>
$('#form_coords').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/coords/save',$(this).serialize(),function(data){
            if (data.ok){
                $('#data').html(data.msg);
                $('#form_coords').each(function(){
                this.reset();
            });
                }
            else{
                   alert(data.msg);
            }
        }, 'json');         
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="linktodjangourl" id="form_coords" method="post">
<input type="text" id="nombre"/>
<input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
</form>
```

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want CSRF protection on your forms you can use the `csrf_exempt` decorator on your forms[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

But make sure you read about [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) before disabling it and take security measure inside 
your views to handle malicious form submissions.

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt